# How can I merge config files from a directory?

Tags: php, laravel, module

I'm using modules in my Laravel code, so while I had in the past used a `/config` directory and handled separate files within there, I'd now like to separate that out.

So, say I have:

`/modules/Users/Config/`

`/modules/Projects/Config/`

I'd like to register all the new config files under both of those directories, then access them like `config(users.fileA)` and `config(users.fileB)` and `config(projects.fileC)`.

However, I can only appear to register/merge config from one file:

```
$this->publishes([
    __DIR__.'/../Config/config.php' => config_path('user.php'),
], 'config');
$this->mergeConfigFrom(
    __DIR__.'/../Config/config.php', 'user'
);
```

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do here?